# Parsing Github response for access_token

Tags: github, go

Just messing around with Github API and oauth. I have got to the point where I receive the `access_token` back from GH.

I have so far:

```
url := "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token"

params := map[string]string{"client_id": client_id, "client_secret": client_secret, "code": code}
data, _ := json.Marshal(params)
resp, _ := http.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(data))

defer resp.Body.Close()

body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

but I would now like to access the response parts. According to the GH docs, they are in the form 
`access_token=e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a&scope=user%2Cgist&token_type=bearer`

Do I need to parse the string or is there a "better" way?

Comment: If you send an `Accept` header to the API (also with `application/json`), you should receive a JSON response that can be unmarshaled.

Answer (score 3):

This is a URL query string.  You can use the `url` package to parse it and get a `url.Values` (which is just a map) out.

```
resp := "access_token=e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a&scope=user%2Cgist&token_type=bearer"
values, err := url.ParseQuery(resp)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("access_token:", values["access_token"])
fmt.Println("token_type:", values["token_type"])
```

[Play link](https://play.golang.org/p/Dk66znSWu-)